# Is it possible to detect a form submission on a page and do my action and then have the form continue as it would normally?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am building a Landing Page A/B Test plugin for WordPress.

My goal is to set up some rules which when met will record a conversion on the current landing page A/B testing variation.

A couple of ideas I have had so far....

### 1)  JavaScript Event Handlers

With JavaScript, detect the submit event and fire an AJAX post to record my conversion inside a event handler.  In the AJAX success callback I will then have it continue on with the post.  One method was to set a flag variable to false and then in the AJAX success set it to true.  Then it would trigger a submit on the form again but this time the flag var would make it bypass the AJAX conversion save and instead just do the normal form post action.

### 2)  Change FORM Action URL to route POST through local server and then forward to destination

With JavaScript, find all matching Forms in the DOM and replace there post action URL with a new URL which is on my server.  THe new URL would make the Form post to my server so that I can detect the post with PHP and record the conversion and then after that I will re-post the original form post data to the original URL.

A Form action URL like this: `https://www.remote-server.com`
would become
`https://www.local-server.com/?record-conversion=yes&id=123&original-url=https://www.remote-server.com`

Then in PHP I can get the FOrms original post URL from `$_POST['original-url']`

To forward the POST to the original URL I have come across 2 PHP functions...

**Version 1**
Prints the form POST data to the HTML page as hidden Form fields and then using JavaScript it triggers to submit the form right away posting the data to the original URL.

```
function redirect_post2($url, array $data)
{
    ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function closethisasap() {
                document.forms["redirectpost"].submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="closethisasap();">
    <form name="redirectpost" method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
        <?php
        if ( !is_null($data) ) {
            foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '"> ';
            }
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="test" value="testval"> ';
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    exit;
}
```

---

**Version 2**
This version uses PHP's `stream_context_create()`, `stream_get_contents()`, and `fopen()` to forward/post the POST data to the original URL.

```
/**
 * Redirect with POST data.
 *
 * @param string $url URL.
 * @param array $post_data POST data. Example: array('foo' => 'var', 'id' => 123)
 * @param array $headers Optional. Extra headers to send.
 */
function redirect_post($url, array $data, array $headers = null) {
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    if (!is_null($headers)) {
        $params['http']['header'] = '';
        foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
            $params['http']['header'] .= "$k: $v\n";
        }
    }
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if ($fp) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo @stream_get_contents($fp);
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
    } else {
        // Error
        throw new Exception("Error loading '$url', $php_errormsg");
    }
}
```

---

### Problems/Issues/Concerns

- If I use the JavaScript event handlers to detect the form post and record my conversion with.  I am not sure what would happen when other event handlers that exist for the same form post/submission exist.  I am not sure if it would make mine not run?  If mine does run and he others do too.  The other handlers might submit the post and then mine could result in the form being submitted more than 1 time!?
- If the Form uses AJAX to submit its post.  Then my code would be trying to do a page redirect post and break the functionality!

---

### Is my goal even possible?

So this leaves me asking the question.  Is it even possibble for me to plugin to a page with existing Forms and be able to record my conversion when the form is submitted and have the Form still perform exactly as it does with out me trying to interfere with it?

Comment: You could try cloning the forms, removing event listeners, then submit original form

Comment: If you don't know anything about the form, it's impossible to avoid breaking things.. There are just too many ways a form can be used. Eg Someone else's code may have a button (not a submit) in there that will read values and then do something based on where (x,y) on the button the user clicked. You could detect the button and event, suppress them, run your own code, reapply the original methods and even fake the button click - but would you have considered making sure your pseudo-click was at the correct location? (Contrived, I know... but there are countless ways/reasons to make a form)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment...

If you have no prior knowledge of how the form works, you can get close - and cover the vast majority of cases you'll see in the wild - but there are going to be some scenarios where you will break the form.

Let's say you do all of the following:

- Detect target form
- Iterate all elements, recording all event handlers
- Clear said event handlers (without somehow breaking validation...)
- Add your own event handler to the form `submit` and all buttons (let's hope the form wasn't submitted by typing a specific value or something else weird, and that all buttons actually did submit the form)
- Wait for a click
- Record the button/event
- Do your AJAX call
- On success (let's ignore what happens on failure)

  - Restore all the original events handlers
  - Attempt to "replay" the event you recorded against the element that your method was invoked from
  - Cross your fingers

That would cover a lot of cases (certainly all the "normal" html form uses), however, it would break in any of the following scenarios:

- Form submission was time-dependent
- Buttons on the form did something else entirely (like make an Ajax request to validate a username)
- Specifics of the event details are used to process the form somehow (eg where on the button a click occured)
- Doesn't handle cases where there's no "click" submission at all (when a specific value is typed into a field, etc...)
- Doesn't handle cases where the submission is invoked from outside the form
- It would also break any validation events, etc.

You could be less aggressive when stripping events out, but then you're more likely to miss the submission entirely.

#### A different approach which is marginally better...

If your own methods are robust enough to survive being called multiple times with no side-effects, you might be able to get away with doing the following:

Replace all form `onsubmit` event handlers with your own wrappers that do something like

```
function handleSubmit(form) {
    // Make your ajax call
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        onsuccess: {
            form.submit();
        }
    })
}
```

That should handle the "stock" case. Then, to handle the case where the original form uses jQuery Ajax, set up a [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) to do something similar (but in this case, instead of submitting a form, you'll invoke the original callback).

Now you're handling stock forms and jQuery AJAX. Of course, if they're using react/angular/a different framework, you'll need to add a handlers for those.

I suppose you could go whole-hog and try to substitute the low-level `XMLHttpRequest` (and associated equivalents in different browsers) but that's going to be *really* fragile.

At the end of a day, you'll be signing up for an arms race and I don't think it's one you can ever win.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The main issue is that I wont know from my plugin or code which Forms exist or do not exist on a page that are added from other plugins or even manually added to the HTML.  So the goal is to make my plugin basically be able to detect any form which has a matching CSS class name and for each form that matches, log an event when that form is submitted and then have the form continue as if I never intercepted it at all.  So I wont know if there are other event handlers for the form and I wont know if the form post using AJAX or not!....

Comment: ...with that said, I feel there might not be any way to do this 100% of the time for any form and have it always work as I want it too.  Now I can detect forms added with Gravity Forms, Ninja forms, Contact 7 forms, etc and plugin to those forms when they submit in the backend easily however this leaves a big gap for forms on the page that are not using those plugins.

Comment: There might be another approach but it's a little... Ugly. You might be able to open websocket to a monitor on webserver (or second tab/iframe) which you could use to send data about form submissions. That would allow you to "phone home" as the form is being submitted and not worry about delaying it. You could attach the phone home method to all form submit events. Unfortunately, there's just no way you can reliably intercept an unknown AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up *onsubmit* attr. at the form.

html

```
<form onsubmit="Get();" method="post" action="example.php">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

javascript

```
var Get = function(){
//action to do
return true
};
```

> 100% tested.on chrom dev.

If you want to run the ajax and then if true is answer continue the form then you need to change the javascript to this:

```
var Get = function(){
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
if (xhttp.responseText == "true"){
return true;
}else{
alert("There is some error in verfication.");
return false;
break;
}
}else{
alert("Oops error " + xhttp.State + " happends.");
return false;
break;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET" , x, true);
/* add 
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
if using post*/
xhttp.send();
};
```

Instead of x in xhttp.open(); type the file as string.

If caching is not an option then change GET to POST, its slower but secure.

> 0% tested